# What is the difference between event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(url)) and async await it in service worker and not waiting at all?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

When I clicked notification, I discovered three ways to open a URL within a service worker:

### 1. Not awaiting it at all

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  const url = event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.notification.click_action;

  clients.openWindow(url);
});
```

### 2. event.waitUntil

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  const url = event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.notification.click_action;

  event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(url));
});
```

### 3. async await

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', async (event) => {
  const url = event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.notification.click_action;

  await self.clients.openWindow(url);
});
```

What is the distinction between these methods?

Can I utilize option 1 for the sake of simplicity?